# Mi petición por Ajax no funciona PHP (mostrando una tabla dependiendo de un option)

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, jquery, ajax

estaba trabajando en hacer que mediante un select cargara una tabla con filtro de area y la solución más factible era usar ajax, (hice el select que hace la llamada a la base de datos para rellenarlo y este si funciona pero al cambiar el select no funciona pero este si me muestra un alert asi que si entra la función o al menos eso parece) si alguien pudiera ayudarme soy muy nuevo en esto y no sé que podría ser

Este es el error que me muestra al inspeccionar:

```
jquery.min.js:4 POST http://192.168.21.209/crear_modificar_preguntas/show.php 500 (Internal Server Error)
send @ jquery.min.js:4
ajax @ jquery.min.js:4
select_area @ preguntas.php:531
onchange @ preguntas.php:666
ListPicker._handleWindowTouchEnd @ desconocida
```

aqui debajo adjunto parte del **codigo principal PHP**

```
       <script>
        function select_area(){
        var x = document.getElementById("area_buscar").value;
        alert(x);
        $.ajax({
            url:"show.php",
            method:"POST",
            data:{
                id : x
            },
            success: function(data){
                $("#ans").html(data);
            }
        })
    }
  </script>

    <?PHP
    $querito = $mysqli->query("SELECT DISTINCT `area` FROM `preguntas`");
     ?>
        <select class='campo_texto' id='area_buscar' onchange="select_area()">
            <?PHP  while ($valores = mysqli_fetch_array($querito)) {
                ?>
                <option value="<?php echo $valores['area'];?>"> <?PHP echo $valores['area'];?> 
   </option>
            <?PHP
            }
            ?>
        </select>

  
    <table align="center">
        <thead>
            <th style="width:20%">Pregunta</th>
            <th style="width:20%">Área</th>
            <th style="width:20%">Porcentaje</th>
        </thead>
        <tbody id="ans">

        </tbody>
    </table>
```

**CODIGO "show.php"**

```
 <?PHP
include('../coneccion.php');

$k = $_POST['id'];
// $k = $_GET['area_buscar'];
$prueba = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM `preguntas` WHERE `area`='$k'");
  while ($rows = mysqli_fetch_array($prueba)) {
?>
    <tr>
        <td><?PHP echo $rows['pregunta'];?></td>
        <td><?PHP echo $rows['area'];?></td>
        <td><?PHP echo $rows['porcentaje'];?></td>
    </tr>

<?PHP
}

echo $prueba;
```

Comment: Mira en el log de errores de PHP a ver si hay algo más de información.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

usa esto quedará mas organizado y funciona igual.

```
 $.ajax({
   url:"show.php",
   method:"POST",
   type: "json",
   data:{id : x},
   success: function(data){
     $("#ans").html(data);
   }
 });
```

en el `show.php` esto:

```
  $rows = mysqli_fetch_array($prueba)
  foreach ($rows as $key => $values) {
    $tr = "
      <tr>
        <td>".$key['pregunta']."</td>
        <td>".$key['area']."</td>
        <td>".$key['porcentaje']."</td>
      </tr>";
  }
  echo json_encode([
    'data' => $tr
  ]);
```

Comment: oh ya veo amigo ahora muchas gracias ya me muestra datos pero solo me muestra el ultimo de esa area (en este caso estoy buscando todas las preguntas del area) tienes alguna idea del porque?

Comment: bueno edito respuesta y prueba si asi funciona mejor, solo no quise alterar mucho tu código pero yo uso mejor el bucle `foreach`

Comment: Muchas gracias amigo me funcionó perfecto :) ya quedó, saludos